# Magento https print order page is empty

Tags: magento

After i changed the checkout page into https the print order page is empty, what i need to change. Please some one help me

Comment: Are there any error codes not displayed but shows when you view source?

Comment: nothing is in the view, what might be the problem

Comment: thanks for your reply RandyMorris. I got its working, the problem from print view file itself.